# decode encoded value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**राम (hindi language)**

I am working on a table where many rows contains value like this `&#2352;&#2366;&#2350;` it shows in browser like राम  and many rows already contains राम  but
I want to replace all encoded value with decode values for this i used find replace query also put data in form and updated but every time db stores encoded  value

Structure of table

```
hindi   varchar(256)    utf8_unicode_ci
```

**what i did**

```
<?php
echo $queryfetch="select hindi from users where id='2'";
$resultfetch=mysqli_query($c,$queryfetch);
while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($resultfetch))
{
echo $queryupdate="update users set hindi='".html_entity_decode($row['hindi'])."' where id='2'";
$resultupdate=mysqli_query($c,$queryupdate);
}
?>
select hindi from users where id='2'

update users set hindi='राम' where id='2'

**
sql before =&#2352;&#2366;&#2350;

**sql after = à¤°à¤¾à¤®**
```

Comment: encrypted != encoded

Comment: And out of interest in your find replace query what did you replace the encoded characters with?

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok i updated my question

Comment: @Riggs Those are *HTML entities*. You can't talk about UTF-8 encoding without looking at the bytes, which we are not here.

Comment: @deceze In my defence, the question has changed a bit since I last looked at it

Comment: @prameshwer Looks like you're decoding your HTML entities, but are then failing to handle UTF-8 correctly to/from the database/browser. See the duplicate.

Comment: @deceze Is there any way in sql to decode all html entities without using any form ?  because i am trying to do this from 2 days and i have more that 15,000 rows

Comment: If for whatever reason you can't convert all the data in one go, you can simply do it "in production": add some sort of flag (column) to note whether a row has been converted or not. Whenever you get data from the database, convert it or not based on that flag. Whenever you *update* the data anyway, do it correctly and then unflag that row. Eventually all your data should be in a sane state. Hopefully your data access layer is sufficiently centralised so you just have to implement this change in very few places…

Answer (score 0):

What you have are html-encoded characters. To decode them, you need:

```
html_entity_decode('&#2352;&#2366;&#2350;')
```

[An example](https://3v4l.org/ADniT).